# Saved VPN configuration requires an update?

Tags: ios, networking, vpn, tunnel, networkextension

I have developed an VPN application when I save the VPN configuration in the system Settings the VPN profile is highlighted in red saying [requires an update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXffO.png) and can't connect.I'm using https://github.com/ss-abramchuk/OpenVPNAdapter

Please help me

Comment: did u get an update ?

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should match the version of iOS targets (your_app & network Extension)

Second, make the version and build targets the same (your_app & network Extension)[image]